# Ubuntu Server DNS Problem with Static IP

Tags: server, dns, netplan

I am running an Ubuntu Server on my VMBox and need to set static IP. By following the steps described in https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/,  I created the configuration file 01-netcfg.yaml as follows.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd        
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.10.21.8/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.21.100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Running `sudo netplan apply --debug`results in:

[image: debug]

Which I'm not sure if the process is succesful or not since it mentions a merged config but gives no error at the end. However, I can not connect to Internet. `sudo ping www.facebook.com` returns "Temporary failure in name resolution". `ping 64.233.169.104` results in "Destination Host Unreachable". `sudo apt-get update` fails as well.

```
sudo lshw -C network:
```

[image]

```
 cat /etc/netplan/*
```

[image]

After trying the answer.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

[image]

```
ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

[image]

```
ls -al /etc/netplan
```

[image]

```
sudo netplan generate --debug
```

[image]

```
sudo netplan apply
```

No output.

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have a `enp0s3` interface? what is the output of `ls /sys/class/net`?

Comment: Do you have more than one .yaml file in /etc/netplan? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Amongst other things, I want to see the name of your ethernet device. You should be using `sudo netplan --debug generate` first, and then `sudo netplan apply`, then `reboot` to confirm operation.

Comment: @steeldriver the output is "enp0s3" and "lo"

Comment: @heynnema there is also 50-cloud-init.yaml and 99-disable-network-config.cfg files, and i updated the question with "sudo lshw -C "

Comment: Ah! Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*`. Then do you have 3 files in /etc/netplan? 2 .yaml and 1 .cfg?

Comment: @heynnema That's right. I added cat /etc/netplan/* . The files are "01-network-card.yaml" "50-cloud-init.yaml", "99-disable-network-config.cfg"

Comment: So, in your question, I believe that you've shown me the `01-network-card.yaml` (or 01-netcfg.yaml as you say in your question) and `"99-disable-network-config.cfg`, correct? What's the content of `50-cloud-init.yaml`? Also show me `cat /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable*`.

Comment: @heynnema the file name is 01-network-card.yaml right know, I had changed it after i asked the question for trying something, sorry for the confusion. The content of 50-cloud-init.yaml is the commented part at the log of cat /etc/netplan/* . cat  /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99* returns nothing since the files there are no file starts with 99. The files are 05_logging.cfg, 50-curtin-networking.cfg, 90_dpkg.cfg, curtin-preserver-sources.cfg and README.

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, give me a couple of minutes to write an answer for you (which you can accept later if it solves your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer...

From the comments...

In `/etc/netplan` we have three files...

```
01-network-card.yaml          # the file that you created
50-cloud-init.yaml            # the file that was already there
99-disable-network-config.cfg # who knows where this file came from
```

`cd /etc/netplan` # change directories

`sudo mv 50-cloud-init.yaml 50-cloud-init.yaml.HOLD` # rename file

`sudo mv 99-disable-network-config.cfg 99-disable-network-config.cfg.HOLD` # rename file

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new configuration

*Note: The new configuration may already work at this point.*

`reboot` # confirm operation

**Update #1:**

The 10.10.21.8 and 10.10.21.100 addresses are not correct. Go back to your instructor and get valid addresses, and then it should all work now. This all works when using `dhcp4: true` instead of static IP's.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't connect the internet after these steps. BTW, I created the 99-disable-network-config.cfg as well.

Comment: But your ping commands failed before, so you were not able to connect to the Internet then either, correct? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/netplan` and the output of the two `sudo netplan...` commands... and `resolvectl`.

Comment: And also `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I edited the question. resolvectl command is not found.

Comment: You couldn't get to the Internet before, correct? Originally, what made you create the two extra files in /etc/netplan? The `sudo netplan --debug generate` only output those 4 lines? If so, that's good. Where did you get the 10.10.21.8 and 10.10.21.100 addresses from? Instead of `resolvectl` try `systemd-resolve --status`.

Comment: Correct. But i can get to Internet without the static IP. These ip addresses are randomly generated. Result of systemd-resolve --status is added.

Comment: Ah! More good info. So without the static address, and if you enter `dhcp4: true` into the .yaml, then it all works, correct? So how did the IP's get randomly generated? The gateway is usually .1.

Comment: Yes without the static IP, and setting dhcp4: true I can connect. It is an assignment and the addresses are generated by using some numbers of our student ID.

Comment: Ah again! Those IP's are wrong. Unless they've setup those specific IP's somewhere on the network, your .yaml file, although syntactically correct, will never work, and pings and Internet will fail. So this situation is not in a production environment, but rather a college/university environment? I think that with the exception of your symlink for /etc/resolv.conf, I think we've gone as far as we can. Temporarily use `dhcp4: true` until you get the correct IP's. Please do come back later and update me, and accept my answer when it's all working, ok?

Comment: I see, so I can't use a random private IP on my local network and connect to Internet?

Comment: Yes, you can use a static IP as long as it isn't already used by somebody else, but the gateway, which is where I suspect your problem is, should be a standard fixed IP that's dependent on your specific network configuration. Ask your instructor for valid IP's, then edit your .yaml, and do the `sudo netplan` commands again.

Comment: @heyynema, Thank you for all your effort. The IP we set does not have to go to online, I've just assumed that I can due to lack of my knowledge about networks.

Comment: @codemonkey try this just for fun... change your .yaml to `dhcp4: true`and run the `sudo netplan` commands, reboot, and see what your ip is. Maybe 10.10.21.x? Reset your .yaml back to static addressing, enter that same ip into `addresses: 10.10.21.x/24`, and set `gateway4: x.x.x.1`. Rerun the `sudo netplan` commands, and see if you can get online now.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying suggestions with no success and since I was also having this issue with a VM machine I was able to finally do an apt-get update/upgrade by just creating another VM NIC on the VM settings.
Ubuntu Server 18.04  reconigzed it right away and configured the new NIC with DHCP.  Apt-get was able to connect to repositories, download and upgrade the install.
I then turned off the Ubuntu VM, removed the secondary NIC form its settings and was able to use Apt-get and ping google.com after rebooting using only the original NIC.
My static IP settings did not changed.